# Using HDFS with Apache Flink RocksDBStateBackend on Windows: Step-by-step tutorial

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

How to configure Apache Flink RocksDBStateBackend setup locally.
System configuration: Win10 + Intellij Idea 2021.3 + Apache Flink 1.9
Now everything works locally with the Memory State Back end.
As I understand it, when starting Idea raises a local Flink cluster with some limitations, but when passing a job, JobExecutionException appears.

1. Is it possible in principle to use hdfs on Windows?
2. To do this, you need to install and configure Hadoop (or something specifically for Windows), or can you do with dependencies in the pom file?
3. hdfs should be local, or is it acceptable to use remote resources, for example hdfs configured on some host?
   Thanks for the answer, versions, links.

tried to do like here:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.3</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/ops/deployment/hadoop.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question mentions both Flink 1.9 and 1.10. Different versions of Flink are not compatible with one another, so if you are using Flink 1.9, you should be referring to the docs for 1.9.

Versions 1.9 and 1.10 of Flink are both very old, and neither version is still supported.

In production, the RocksDBStateBackend should be configured to use a distributed file system (such as HDFS) for checkpointing. But for testing and development you can use the local disk instead.

For Flink to use HDFS, it needs to have a local installation of the libraries, and you need to set the HADOOP_CLASSPATH environment variable (https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/ops/deployment/hadoop.html) so that Flink can add those libraries to its CLASSPATH.

It doesn't matter if the actual HDFS file system is local or remote.

I have no idea about using Hadoop with Windows.